# Is there a difference between setting a property with the dot or the bracket syntax?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, declared-property

Given the property declaration below, does method (A) work in exactly the same way as method (B)? I just want to check that `self.yellowViewController = yellcon_New;` is going via my setter, so that the old objects gets released and the new one retained.

```
// INTERFACE
@property(nonatomic, retain) YellowViewController *yellowViewController;

// IMPLEMENTATION (A)
self.yellowViewController = yellcon_New;

// IMPLEMENTATION (B)
[self setYellowViewController:yellcon_New];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is correct :

```
self.yellowViewController = yellcon_New;
```

And

```
[self setYellowViewController:yellcon_New];
```

Work the same.
I would like to add something interesting : when you use

```
yellowViewController = yellcon_New;
```

you associate directly the value to the ivar, without going through your setter methode.

So if you have

```
-(void)setYellowViewController:(YellowViewController*)theYellowViewController;
{
    NSLog(@"Setting the yellow view controller");
    [yourWife askFor:beer];
    ...whatever...
    ...set the yellowViewController (retain in your case)
}
```

Calling

```
self.yellowViewController = yellcon_New;
```

and

```
[self setYellowViewController:yellcon_New];
```

will use the setter method (and log the message, and make your wife bring you some beer)

but

```
yellowViewController = yellcon_New;
```

will not.

It's interesting to know this in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, A and B lines work the same

You can check that by using @dynamic instead of @synthesize for this property and put NSLog message in you implementation of setter method.

Comment: No need for @dynamic.  If you implement a setter method, the compiler won't generate a setter.

Comment: ...which is important, because you can use this to still generate the getter if you need a custom setter, or vice-versa. It's also good for adding logging to one of the accessors quickly for debugging purposes, without changing too much of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you're using the `@synthesize` thing for that property, it's creating a `-setYellowViewController:` method for you.