# label.text or NString *textForLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, nsstring

Yesterday when I was making a label for my project I discovered that I can use two formats for displaying text on screen:

```
label.text = @"Hello world";
```

And

```
NSString* textForLabel =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello world"];
[label setText:textForLabel];
```

They both do the same thing.
**Question** - which one is better to use for app development and why?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642735/difference-between-text-and-settext and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207810/is-there-a-difference-between-setting-a-property-with-the-dot-or-the-bracket-syn .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringwithFormat is used in those cases when dynamically you want to pass some value in string.

Morever refer :-

http://programmingbulls.com/stringwithformat

So if you just need to pass a string without need to pass any particular value in it then do not use stringwithformat.

Answer (score 2):

The first one, because it's shorter, more obvious and it doesn't create a string from a string where that string isn't a format but incurs the processing cost of checking it as a format just to find it has no parameter insertion.

Comment: the first one - in this particular case only.  The second if you're building a string with parameters.